# How to refactor almost duplicate methods with generic types

Tags: generics, .net-3.5, c#-3.0, refactoring

I have a few methods that are practically the same except they have a different number of generic type parameters. Inner code is very very similar:

```
public Set[] CreateSet<TFirst, TSecond>(List<TFirst> first, List<TSecond> second)
{
    Set[] result = new Set[2];
    result[0] = CreateSet(first);
    result[1] = CreateSet(second);
    return result;
}

public Set[] CreateSet<TFirst, TSecond, TThird>(List<TFirst> first, List<TSecond> second, List<TThird> third)
{
    Set[] result = new Set[3];
    result[0] = CreateSet(first);
    result[1] = CreateSet(second);
    result[2] = CreateSet(third);
    return result;
}

...
```

And so on. I have these methods up to 7 generic type parameters. As you can see they're practically all the same except that they create a different size array of sets.

**I don't like this code duplication so would it be possible to refactor this code into a single private method that these would internally call.** Or should I consider any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could create a builder for the set collection e.g.

```
public class SetCollectionBuilder
{
    private readonly List<Set> sets = new List<Set>();
    public SetCollectionBuilder Add<T>(List<T> list)
    {
        this.sets.Add(CreateSet(list));
        return this;
    }

    public Set[] Build()
    {
        return this.sets.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Then you could create an arbitrary collection like:

```
Set[] result = new SetCollectionBuilder()
    .Add(first)
    .Add(second)
    .Build();
```

Comment: This is actually clever. I was using `ref` variables on my original methods (didn't bother with this detail in my question) and I've adjusted your code to support that and it actually works. Much cleaner and much less repetitive. Now I can only hope I could have the possibility of `params` like generic types parameters... Then I'd only need one single method definition for all of them,

Comment: You know what? I removed my methods and use the builder directly in my code. So much less lines of code. I'll give you +1 as well that's how grateful am I for this answer. :)

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: Can you show how you would do anything remotely similar with ref parameters?

Comment: @supercat: Here you go: [BLToolkit MapResultSet builder](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/08/bltoolkit-mapresultset-builder.html) blog post.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: Thanks.  Unfortunately, that approach wouldn't help with the scenario I'm interested in, which would require that an unknown number of 'ref' parameters passed to an outer function be passed to an inner function as 'ref' parameters.  Thanks for writing anyway, though.

Comment: @supercat: If what you're implying to is `Outer(ref params object[] o)` then yes... this will not work. But if you have a `Outer(ref object o1, ref object o2, ...)` then it would work. Number of parameters is static and inside of this method you know how many times you'd have to call `Add(ref oX)`.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: The difficulty is that when the first 'add' method returns, its ref parameter will cease to exist.  The thing it refers to won't, of course, but it will no longer be possible to use the ref to update the referrent.  In your scenario, the 'add' method writes to the passed-in ref, and that ref need never be written again.  What I'd like to see would be a type-safe means by which a property-ish thing could provide true value-by-reference semantics.  If one has e.g. an Array of Rectangle, one can easily say Arr[5].Height = 9; unfortunately,...

Comment: ...there's no clean way for a custom class to provide such functionality. One could expose a method which would take a closure that had a single ref parameter and invoke that closure with the appropriate array element. That would work, but would entail creating an otherwise-unnecessary heap instance, and would not allow the array element to be passed to any routine which had more than one ref parameter. A variadic generic would avoid these limits. Care to chat?

Comment: @supercat let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2173/discussion-between-robert-koritnik-and-supercat)